# How to synchronize to curves on matplotlib?

Tags: python, list, numpy, matplotlib, synchronization

I have two curves that have their maximum roughly at the same time, but I'd like to match them exactly.
The first function, `maxind`, determines where the maximum is on my temporal list.
The 2nd function, `synchro` (where I need help), should synchronize them.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def generate_examples(shift=+1.0):
    # Generate two curves with different maximum
    xa = np.linspace(start=0, stop=6, num=1000)
    xb = np.linspace(start=0, stop=6, num=2000)

    ya = np.sin(xa)
    yb = np.sin(xb+shift)**3
    return (xa, ya), (xb, yb)


def maxind(T, L):
    n = len(L)
    M = - np.inf
    ind = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if L[i] > M:
            ind = i
            M = L[i]
    return ind, M, T[ind]


def synchro(xs, ys, TC, XT):
    indth, maxth, tth = maxind(xs, ys)
    indexp, maxexp, texp = maxind(TC, XT)
    L = []
    Tsync = []
    if indexp < indth:
        I = indth - indexp
        for i in range(I):
            xs.pop(0)
            ys.pop(0)
    else:
        I = indexp - indth
        for i in range(I, len(XT)):
            L.append(XT[i])
            Tsync.append(TC[i])

    return Tsync, L


(xa, ya), (xb, yb) = generate_examples(shift=+1.0)
Tsync, L = synchro(ys=xa, xs=ya, XT=xb, TC=yb)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xa, ya, color='blue', label='a')
ax.plot(xb, yb, color='red', ls=':', label='b')
ax.plot(L, Tsync, color='red', label='synced')

ax.legend()
```

I want to put the max of the red curve at the same point in time as the max of the blue curve.

[image: img]

Comment: can you provide a fully reproducible example, a picture of the current plot and a schematic of the expected output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @mozway How which website should I share it ? I once put an imgur photo and people from here told me that they wouldn't click on it.
Also, I could provide data but I don't know how

Comment: you can use the tool to upload an image directly in the editor, SO will take care of uploading the image

Comment: @Pam thanks. The code is still not reproducible so we can't really do anything with it. Anyway, can you compute the position of the max of each curve? Then get the x delta and subtract (or add) this difference to the x of the second curve. Please provide actual data for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to construct a working example from the code you provided.

My solution uses `numpy` as this makes some things easier, for example you can use directly the `argmax` function instead of coding your own `maxind` function. See the comments in the code to understand the logic behind calculating the index shift for the curve b.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def generate_examples(shift=+1.0):
    # Generate two curves with different maximum
    xa = np.linspace(start=0, stop=6, num=1000)
    xb = np.linspace(start=0, stop=6, num=2000)
    # note that this is a general case where the two curves have different x values,
    # if we assume that they are the same some calculations would become simpler

    ya = np.sin(xa)
    yb = np.sin(xb+shift)**3  # shift maximum by defined value
    return (xa, ya), (xb, yb)


def calculate_shift(xa, ya, xb, yb):
    # Get (first) maximum for a and b
    iya = np.argmax(ya)
    iyb = np.argmax(yb)

    # Get the shift in terms of x
    dx = xb[iyb] - xa[iya]
    print('Shift', dx)  # should be roughly +/-1, as we build the examples this way

    # Find the shift in xb | find the index of xb which is closest to the shift in x
    xb0 = xb - xb[0]  # shift xb to ensure it starts with 0
    dxb = np.abs(dx) - xb0
    ixb = np.argmin(np.abs(dxb))

    # returned the signed shift in indices of xb
    return int(ixb * np.sign(dx))


def plot(xa, ya, xb, yb,
         ixb):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(xa, ya, color='blue', label='a')
    ax.plot(xb, yb, color='red', ls=':', label='b')
    if ixb > 0:
        ax.plot(xb[:-ixb], yb[ixb:], color='red', label='b - shifted')
    else:
        ax.plot(xb[-ixb:], yb[:ixb], color='red', label='b - shifted')

    ax.legend()


(xa, ya), (xb, yb) = generate_examples(shift=-1.0)
ixb = calculate_shift(xa, ya, xb, yb)
plot(xa, ya, xb, yb, ixb)
```

[image: Two Shifts]